# Tag users in a comment similar to instagram in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, instagram, tagging

I am working on an app which is similar to instagram. Which contain a list of images posted by friends, Each image has a list of comments and in these comments user can tag other person by using `@username` . Please see the screenshot

[image]

See the words in red colour i.e `@carlos` or `@fernando_cabrera` . And when user will click on `@carlos` tag, he can see carlos's profile in new screen.

The problem I am facing is that I am making these comments via UIlabel. How can I make these tags clickable and add an action them.

I could add the touch gesture on label in case of one tag. but what if label contains more than one tag. Is there any other approach I should follow. This functionality is exactly same like Instagram. Please someone help me , I am really close to deadlines and I am stuck in this part :(

Comment: Bind user id with `@carlos` when you tag `carlos`.

Comment: I know this. but the question is slightly different dear :). How do I make tags in UIlabel in UI. so that user click on them and being able to see profile

Comment: Try this :- https://github.com/Datt1994/DPTagDetectionTextView

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found an cool SDK [IFTweetlabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iftweetlabel) to make tags within the UIlabel. This is what I needed